# According to Kant, which one is an autonomous being: me or my rationality?

Tags: ethics, kant, rationality

If we consider a person's identity lies not in his rationality, but in, say, his body or his consciousness, then it seems not so obvious why we can regard *a person* as autonomous simply from the status of his *rationality*. (I do think a person and his rationality are seperate things, in the same way as a mobile hard drive or external graphics card is seperate from the computer it is connected to)

Moreover, let's consider a corner case: in which point of evolution do humans gain autonomy? It seems unlikely that a pair of parents without autonomy can suddenly give birth to a autonomous child. Restricting autonomy to rationality itself can possibly avoid this question.

On the other hand, if we claim that rationality itself (instead of the person possessing it) is an autonomous being, then it seems questionable why many of our desires should be protected **as an end** (instead of mere means to accomplish my rationality's will). For example, when I am tortured and desperately wanting to stop the pain, does this urge really comes from my rationality at all? Or maybe it purely comes from the non-rational part of me (as for a non-human animal)?

I am new to this topic. Please correct me if I made any mistake.

Comment: You speak about identity: identity is a subjective knowledge. When I refer to my identity (the object), I am the observer (the subject) of myself. As such, my knowledge can be quite subjective about the object in question. Then, you speak about autonomy, which is also a quite biased knowledge (I might think the kid is autonomous, you might think he's not). Anyway, you are probably looking for Kant's concept _unity of the self_, which would adjust to what you seem to define, and which holds rationality within and would define identity. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness-unity/

Comment: What about me, insofar I am rational? My rational will still is **my** will. That is exactly his solution, so he does explicitly **not** share your sentiment about different entities. Will write an answer with quotes as soon as I am home.